# How to setup PyCharm so '^M' doesn't show up in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, ide, pycharm

When I load .py edited with PyCharm for Win on Ubuntu platform, I can see each line
trailed with ^M.

Is there a setting in PyCharm that I can avoid this annoying character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Settings` | `Code Style` | `General` | `Line Separator`, set to **\n** (Unix).