# Getting special character (^M) in python code (using pycharm IDE) . Showing in git diff . How to remove this?

Tags: python, permissions, pycharm, gitlab, file-permissions

[Here's an image showing the character.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4opp.pngstrong)

My code:

```
class FleetScheduledService(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        authenticated, user_id = auth_with_token_user_id(request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'))
        if not authenticated:
            return UnauthorizedResponse(data_status=False, message="Please login again")
        fleets = list(DB["fleet"].find({"user_ids": user_id}))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Settings | Code Style | General | Line Separator, set to \n (Unix).
```

Taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7688610/5404694)

Comment: Since it's always a good idea to understand why you are changing your settings, there is further information available in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260293/text-file-with-m-on-each-line.